# Is recursive looping in MySQL queries possible?

Tags: mysql, nested

I'm writing myself a forum, and I want to have one of those "you are here" strings along the top ("home > forum > sub forum > topic > etc" kind of thing). Now, the depth the forums can go to is limited to something like 128 by TINYINT in the database, not that this matters.

My question is this: is there a way to select the current forum (using it's ID - easy), but also select everything else it is inside of so I can generate the "you are here" string? Obviously "Home > " is hard coded, but the rest will be titles of forums and sub forums.

I'd need some sort of loop, starting from the deepest level forum I'm currently in and moving up to the top. Is the only way to do it using PHP loops and lots of queries? I'd rather just use one as it's faster.

Thanks,

James

Comment: What you need is a hierarchical query, but MySQL doesn't support these directly. You can work around this by creating a stored function. See here for some (admittedly rather old) tips: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=2341

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, once you have the initial ID, can't you just quickly use a PHP loop to generate a set of variables that you use to generate a "where" statement for your SQL query?

Comment: I've decided on a PHP loop to do the heavy lifting for me. Thanks for the notion of processing using MySQL not PHP - one query means fast query :) Welcom to Stack Overflow bikeboy!

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with a trivially simple query, no joins... if you change your schema to make that information easy to extract. Look up the [nested set model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look into that tomorrow as it's getting late :-)

Comment: Nested sets is what I use for creating my web site navigation.  Very powerful stuff.  There's a good article about doing it in MySQL here: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a previous answer of mine which might be of use: [Recursively check the parents of a child in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021776/recursively-check-the-parents-of-a-child-in-a-database/4023745#4023745)

It's a non recursive single call from php to db using a stored procedure...

```
-- TABLES

drop table if exists pages;
create table pages
(
page_id smallint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
title varchar(255) not null,
parent_page_id smallint unsigned null,
key (parent_page_id)
)
engine = innodb;

-- TEST DATA

insert into pages (title, parent_page_id) values
('Page 1',null), 
('Page 2',null), 
   ('Page 1-2',1), 
      ('Page 1-2-1',3), 
      ('Page 1-2-2',3), 
   ('Page 2-1',2), 
   ('Page 2-2',2);


-- STORED PROCEDURES

drop procedure if exists page_parents;

delimiter #

create procedure page_parents
(
in p_page_id smallint unsigned
)
begin

declare v_done tinyint unsigned default 0;
declare v_depth smallint unsigned default 0;

create temporary table hier(
 parent_page_id smallint unsigned, 
 page_id smallint unsigned, 
 depth smallint unsigned default 0
)engine = memory;

insert into hier select parent_page_id, page_id, v_depth from pages where page_id = p_page_id;

/* http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html */

create temporary table tmp engine=memory select * from hier;

while not v_done do

    if exists( select 1 from pages pg inner join hier on pg.page_id = hier.parent_page_id and hier.depth = v_depth) then

        insert into hier 
            select pg.parent_page_id, pg.page_id, v_depth + 1 from pages pg
            inner join tmp on pg.page_id = tmp.parent_page_id and tmp.depth = v_depth;

        set v_depth = v_depth + 1;          

        truncate table tmp;
        insert into tmp select * from hier where depth = v_depth;

    else
        set v_done = 1;
    end if;

end while;

select 
 pg.page_id,
 pg.title as page_title,
 b.page_id as parent_page_id,
 b.title as parent_page_title,
 hier.depth
from 
 hier
inner join pages pg on hier.page_id = pg.page_id
left outer join pages b on hier.parent_page_id = b.page_id
order by
 hier.depth, hier.page_id;

drop temporary table if exists hier;
drop temporary table if exists tmp;

end #

delimiter ;

-- TESTING (call this stored procedure from php)

call page_parents(5);
call page_parents(7);
```

Comment: I will definitely look into this when I have more time - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume the user navigated using the physical hierarchy of the forums, just use a lot of left joins as follows:

```
select current.forum as current,
        parent1.forum as history1,
        parent2.forum as history2,
        parent3.forum as history3,
        parent4.forum as history4,
        parent5.forum as history5,
        parent6.forum as history6
from forum current
left join forum parent1 on parent1.id = current.parentid
left join forum parent2 on parent2.id = parent1.parentid
left join forum parent3 on parent3.id = parent2.parentid
left join forum parent4 on parent4.id = parent3.parentid
left join forum parent5 on parent5.id = parent4.parentid
left join forum parent6 on parent6.id = parent5.parentid
```

Otherwise, you may want to create a forum breadcrumb table to store the history of locations the user has visited.  Update this table with each location the user visits.

Comment: A breadcrumb table would be ok, but I think a PHP loop is the best option here. Thanks all the same though :-)

Comment: that's overkilled, and where is the `where`? u trying to dump everything out