# MySQL - Recursing a tree path between two nodes

Tags: mysql, binary-search-tree

I want to get the path between two nodes using MYSQL recursion, subquery, without using Procedure/,function

My table is

link

```
+--------+--------+
| child  | parent | 
+--------+--------+
|      5 |      1 | 
|      3 |      1 | 
|      2 |      3 | 
|      4 |      3 | 
|      6 |      4 | 
+--------+--------+
```

Ex: path between child 6 and child 5 is 6-4-3-1-5

Comment: 'Nested sets' may be useful: [316267/help-with-writing-a-sql-query-for-nested-sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316267/help-with-writing-a-sql-query-for-nested-sets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry. `MySQL` AND `recursion` AND `without using Procedure/function` is not possible.

While true recursion is not possible, for limited number of levels, it is possible to do multiple join like

```
FROM mytable t0
LEFT JOIN mytable t1 ON t1.parent=t0.child
LEFT JOIN mytable t2 ON t2.parent=t1.child
LEFT JOIN mytable t3 ON t3.parent=t2.child
LEFT JOIN mytable t4 ON t4.parent=t3.child
...
```

but that is only for limited depth and highly ineffective