# How to get sons without grandsons of a node design in nested set model?

Tags: sql, database, algorithm, postgresql

I use PostgreSQL, and I have design a model, nested set model, for a table containing relationship.

As a node in the model, every row obviously should has the fields "lft" and "rgt", further more, **I have add the field parent_id(referring to its parent node)**, which is self-explaining.

The model which is convenient for querying all the sub-node of the node specified, but now I just want to fetch its children but not all of its descendants in a high performance way.

[image: each node has a field "pid" referring to its parent node]

Could you help me? Thanks very much!

**I have found the answer**.==>[Help with writing a SQL query for Nested Sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316267/help-with-writing-a-sql-query-for-nested-sets?rq=1)

Comment: Please provide us with a table example and your queries so far.

Comment: "*I have add the field parent_id(referring to its parent node)*" - why are you maintaining two different implementations of the hierarchy?

Comment: I don't worry the insert performance but the fetching performance is important, so I think adding the parent_id makes it more flexible and do it.

Comment: In terms of output and for clarity, is it correct to say you want records (in brackets) 2,5 & 6?

Comment: for example, i want to get the (4)'s children, the output should be (5) and (6)   , (7) should be excluded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *
from table as t_children
where t_children.parent_id in (
    select *
    from table as t_parent
    where t_parent.parent_id is null
)
```

Comment: no......sorry....I just want to fetch children a specified node but not all the parent. And it seem has a poor performance

Comment: Just change the `where` clause for the inner select - and why should it have a poor performance? The outer select works on the ID, just add an index.

Comment: Although I think it's too late, you should consider an index on `parent_id` to speed up the outer select statement